How to list folders of 200 MB+ but excluding redundant parent folders
I'd love a command that produces something like the result of cd /myChosenFolder && du -aBM 2>/dev/null | sort -nr except excluding folders less than 200M.
And then from that first step, for each of the lowest level children folders, it should go back and omit all of its parent / grandparent / etc folders from the list since that information is redundant, and the root cause of my disk usage is already visible in that 200+ MB subfolder.

New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78715820/find-subfolders-using-a-lot-of-disk-space

du has a -t option which allows to print only entries that are above / below a certain size.
Also, sort has an -h option which allows to sort lines comparing human-readable numbers, so you don't really need to pass -BM to du to scale the entries' size to M, you could just pass -h to both du and sort and get a nice human-readable list as the output (which will appropriately report T / G / M and so on).
Removing all the parents from each entry can be done using sed and applying this substitution: s/([^\t]+\t).*\//\1/.
Putting everything toghether:
du -aht 200M 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | sed -E 's/([^\t]+\t).*\//\1/'

% for n in {1..3}; do dd if=/dev/zero of=above_200M_$n bs=1M count=201; done
201+0 records in
201+0 records out
210763776 bytes (211 MB, 201 MiB) copied, 0.145887 s, 1.4 GB/s
201+0 records in
201+0 records out
210763776 bytes (211 MB, 201 MiB) copied, 0.138272 s, 1.5 GB/s
201+0 records in
201+0 records out
210763776 bytes (211 MB, 201 MiB) copied, 0.139544 s, 1.5 GB/s
% touch below_200M_{1..3}
% du -aht 200M 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | sed -E 's/([^\t]+\t).*\//\1/'
604M    .
202M    above_200M_3
202M    above_200M_2
202M    above_200M_1


Thanks so much for this work. I bet this is very close to what I'm looking for. When I said "go back and omit all of its parent / grandparent / etc folders from the list since that information is redundant", what I meant is to delete any rows from the output that are of parent / grandparent / etc folders of other folders in the output. And then the results themselves should show the sizes and full paths. E.g. 1.2G /apps/example1, 1.1G /apps/example1/big_folder, 300M /apps/example2 would then omit the 1.2G   /apps/example1 row. Thanks so much for what you've done!

@Ryan No problem, I'll see if I can adjust this to work like that, but I think some logic is required to drive the removal of the unwanted lines. I don't think it's doable using only existing tools and some parsing.

@Ryan I tried (with 3 different approaches :|), whatever method I attempted wasn't robust enough (simple Bash script, simple Perl commands, a mix of those and regular commands). It'd take a full blown Perl script at least to tackle this correctly, there are too many edge cases. Let's see if someone finds a simpler way for the time being :| sorry, hopefully I'm missing a relatively easy solution that it's somewhere out there

Thank you so much for trying! I really appreciate your effort.

It's what you're going for, but it's a bit long.
dir -1Rsh --quoting-style=shell-always | grep -A 1 --no-group-separator -v "\\./" | grep -B 1 --no-group-separator -E '[2-9][0-9]{2,}M|[1-9][0-9]+G' | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF) ":\n" $(NF+1)}' | sed "s|':||;s|\'||g" | awk 'NF'

grep
-A 1 Result + one line after, -v Invert match, -B 1 Result + one line before
-E Extended regular expressions'[2-9][0-9]{2,}M|[1-9][0-9]+G' Extract entries with sizes 200M+
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF) ":\n" $(NF+1)}' Split the input on the / character.
sed "s|':||;s|\'||g" Remove single quotes and colons.
awk 'NF' Removes blank lines
Strip the : off of every line, | to:
 perl -nl -e 'print substr($_, 0, (length($_) - 1))'


Thanks for your answer. Can you please add some description about what it is doing in each part? I'm looking forward to trying this when I'm on my other computer! Thanks.

[2-9][0-9]{2,}M won't allow any size starting with 1 to match, so for example 1000M would be discarded. I strongly suggest avoiding trying to match ranges of numbers using regexes, it's extremely easy to get it wrong.

@kos Good call.  I removed -k from dir.  That should solve the problem.

Now it won't match any size expressed in G not including a dot, e.g. 1G, 2G, 10G... or anything including and above T regardless of a dot. I promise you, I've been there, it's not going to be easy :)

@kos Haha. That one IS tough... hmmm.

You could check if dir has an option to scale sizes to a certain unit (I'm unsure whether it does), or resort to OP's idea to scale sizes using du. And yeah it is tough to match even simple ranges using regexes, let alone match human readable ranges. That's why I'd try and avoid it altoghether :)

@kos That might do it...

Thanks for your effort on this! Currently the output is https://imgur.com/a/0FGsqKU Please also see a clarification at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1517503/how-to-list-folders-of-200-mb-but-excluding-redundant-parent-folders/1517612#comment2664997_1517612 Thanks for your help.

@Ryan I may be closer, if separate lines are okay.

Thanks for the new answer. The result now looks similar to before but without any red text: https://imgur.com/a/dytSRVB

@Ryan Just add: grep -v '4.0K ' after the dir to remove them. Like this: dir -1Rsh --quoting-style=shell-always | grep -v '4.0K ' | grep -A 1...  Make sure you have a space after the K.

A new version of my question is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78715820/470749 and getting some interesting answers. Thanks for all of your help earlier.
